# Endnotes in plain TeX

Tags: plain-tex, endnotes

Are there macros available for creating endnotes in Plain TeX?

I am sure I can write these myself but would prefer to free ride on someone else's effort.

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/endnote possibly?

Comment: @PaulGessler:  This is just slightly imperfect but will be very easy to modify.  It's 99% of what I was looking for.  Thanks very much.  If you convert this to an answer, I'll look forward to accepting it.

Comment: Done, glad it will help. And by the way: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`endnote` from CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endnote) may give a suitable starting point. Here's a quick example:

```
\input endnote

Hello world! This is to have an endnote. \endnote{[1]}{ Endnote text.}

\producenotes

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Its simplicity is a plus.

Comment: Many thanks. It works on Optex too, and is much, much simpler than anything out there. If one uses chapters, it suffices to declare `\enotecounter=0` at the beginning of each chapter.

Answer (score 6):

You can be inspired by [OPmac trick 0051](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks.html#gloslast). Here is my clumsy translation of this OPmac trick:

**Glossary at the end of the document**

The abbreviations or some else can be occurred in the document and we
need to write some explanations of such objects at the end of the document. We
write `\glos{abbreviation}{explanation}`. Nothing occurs in this place of the
document. For example:

```
\input opmac
...
I am working at CTU\glos{CTU}{Czech Technical University in Prague} in Prague.
```

The macro `\glos` saves the information into memory and uses them at the
place where `\makeglos` is used. You can implement `\glos` and `\makeglos` by:

```
\def\gloslist{}
\def\glos #1#2{%
   \expandafter\isinlist\expandafter\gloslist\csname;#1\endcsname
   \iftrue \opwarning{Duplicated glossary item `#1'}%
   \else 
      \global\sdef{;#1}{{#1}{#2}}%
      \global\expandafter\addto\expandafter\gloslist\csname;#1\endcsname
   \fi
}
\def\makeglos{%
   \ifx\gloslist\empty \opwarning{Gossary data unavailable}%
   \else
      \bgroup
        \let\iilist=\gloslist
        \dosorting
        \def\act##1{\ifx##1\relax \else \expandafter\printglos##1\expandafter\act\fi}
        \expandafter\act\iilist\relax
      \egroup
   \fi
}
\newdimen\glosindent  \glosindent=2\parindent
\def\printglos #1#2{\noindent \hangindent=\glosindent \hbox to\glosindent{#1\hss-- }#2\par}
```

The glossary is automatically sorted by the alphabet. If you needn't such
sorting and the order by the occurrence is sufficient then you can comment
out the `\dosorting` sequence in the `\makeglos` definition.

Of course, you can program the `\printglos` by your wish, by your
typography design. The `\printglos` macro has two parameters:
`{abbverviation}{explanation}` and it prints one glossary item in the list.
The `\printglos` defined above sets fixed indentation `2\parindent` for all
items. You can use another indentation, for example the indentation can be
calculated from the maximal lenght of the abbverviation, see 
[OPmac trick 0041](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-enn.html#bibmarkindent)

Another more simple example of the `\printglos`:

```
\def\printglos #1#2{\noindent #1 -- #2\par}
```

Explanation: The `\glos` macro saves `\;abbver1` `\;abbver2` etc. into
`\gloslist` and defines `\;abbver1` as `{abbver1}{explanation}`, `\;abbver2`
as `{abbver2}{explanation}` etc. The macro `\makeglos` converts `\gloslist` to
`\iilist` locally and does the alphabeticaly sorting by the macro `\dosorting`
from OPmac. Finally, the `\act` macro prints the items.

Relevant OPmac tricks:

- [Glossary at the begin of the document](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-enn.html#glosfirst)
- [Glossary sorted by Czech sorting rules](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-enn.html#glossort)
- [Glossary with hyperlinks](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-enn.html#glosref)

Comment: This is basically a kludge: use OPmac's glossary engine to fake endnotes.