# Endnotes on same line in PlainTex/Optex by chapter

Tags: plain-tex, optex, eplain

Both answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225774/endnotes-in-plain-tex) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684402/sequential-one-line-endnotes-in-plain-tex-optex/684406#684406) provide solutions for endnotes in plain/optex.

However, the latter solution cannot restart every chapter, whereas the former aren't sequential/one-line.

Is there any way to merge both solutions in order to:

- make the first solution a one-paragraph, sequencial series of notes restarting each chapter, **and/or**
- make the second solution restart every chapter?

The first solution is quite simple (and hence prefereable?):

> \input endnote
>
> Hello world! This is to have an endnote. \enote{Endnote text.}
>
> \producenotes
>
> \bye

Comment: See the edit to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684406/270600

Comment: @MaxChernoff Thank you so much!

Comment: I wonder if the crossreference makes this question a duplicate...